# Dual monitor setup fail

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga

I have a Sony VPCEA36FG (the US equivalent is VPCEA33FD). The graphics card on it is an AMD- 5650 1 gb card so it does support 2 external monitors. It has VGA and HDMI ports on it.

I want to hook my laptop to 2 external monitors. They are LCDs but unfortunately only with VGA ports. Currently, I can view the same output on both my external monitors (through a VGA splitter) and extend it to my laptop, hence running 3 displays simultaneously.

I want to extend the windows on both the external monitors and not show anything on my laptop's display. Unfortunately, when i plug  the vga cable to my laptop, it overlaps with the HDMI port so I can't really go HDMI to VGA for the second monitor.